# How to find the tab and refresh it in browser by name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 open tabs from same application and same domain: tab1 and tab2, they are not opened from each other I mean I can not use `win.open(....)` and `win.reload()` So is there any way to find the tab by name and refresh it. The objective is from tab1 find the tab2 and refresh it automatically. any idea?

Comment: how is the application opening the windows?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 solutions to your problem:

1. check if your document focus has changed. You only need to refresh it when tab gets visible again.
2. register open tabs in a session array and flag them with ajax calls or with server side code if they need to refresh. each page (tab) can check it's flag, refresh itself if needed and clear flag. I will need to know what might trigger the need to refresh for a better approach.